# Remove encoding from XmlWriter

Tags: c#, xml

I'm using XmlWriter and XmlWriterSettings to write an XML file to disk.  However, the system that is parsing the XML file is complaining about the encoding.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

What it wants is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
```

If I try OmitXmlDeclaration = true, then I don't get the xml line at all.

```
string destinationName = "C:\\temp\\file.xml";
string strClassification = "None";

XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Indent = true;

using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(destinationName, settings))
{
    writer.WriteStartDocument();
    writer.WriteStartElement("ChunkData");
    writer.WriteElementString("Classification", strClassification);
    writer.WriteEndElement();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the system is complaining about the `encoding` attribute? I think it's complaining about the encoding of the whole XML.

Comment: `However, the system that is parsing the XML file is complaining about the encoding.` Where is it's code? Seems to be an **[XY-Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=XY+Problem)**

Comment: addy, yes, it's probably the encoding. I thought that removing that tag would fix it, but apparently not.  L.B, I have no control over the code of the other system.  They provided XML files that parsed just fine and did not have the encoding tag.

Comment: @MathewPatterson `They provided XML files` then you should *read* them. Why do you want to write/create xml files? What am I missing?

Comment: The XML files they provided were an example.  If I place those XML files in a specific directory on a server, the application parses them and does *stuff*.  I need to create XML files that do *other things* based on what a user is doing.  However, the program I made has encoded XML files, the files they provided have no encoding.

Comment: So I guess a better question is, how do I use XmlWriter to create XML files that aren't encoded?

Comment: @MathewPatterson, XML files, like any other text files, are *always* encoded... The encoding is just the way text is represented in binary. Common encodings include ASCII, ISO-8859-1 (aka Latin1 or Windows1252), UTF-8, UTF-16, etc

Comment: The `encoding` attribute is just here to help the parser detect which encoding is used in the file, but even if it isn't there, there is an encoding... Try to set `settings.Encoding = Encoding.Default`

Comment: http://www.cookcomputing.com/blog/archives/000577.html

Comment: @ThomasLevesque this put encoding="Windows-1252" into the XML file, however, it looks like the application will accept this encoding.

Comment: @har07 I also checked this out, and was able to get it to work.  Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 6):

Just ran into this ---

1. remove the `XmlWriterSettings()` altogether and use the `XmlTextWriter()'s Formatting` field for indention.
2. pass in `null` for the `Encoding` argument of `XmlTextWriter's ctor`

The following code will create the output that you're looking for: 
`<?xml version="1.0" ?>`

```
var w = new XmlTextWriter(filename, null);
w.Formatting = Formatting.Indented; 
w.WriteStartDocument(); 
w.WriteStartElement("ChunkData");
w.WriteEndDocument(); 
w.Close();
```

The `.Close()` effectively creates the file - the `using` and `Create()` approach will also work.

Comment: Unfortunately **XmlTextWriter** cannot write to a **StringBuilder**. (or a **String** for that matter)

Comment: @IanBoyd - haven't tried that - but if need be, you could always write the file & read its contents into a string ...