# Why does XDeclaration ignore the encoding parameter I set

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

### The problem

I am trying to generate a XML file with the `XDeclaration` that should result in the following

`<?xml version="1.0"?>`.

What I keep getting when I run my piece of code is this

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`.

So the problem is, no matter what I change in the encoding parameter of my `XDeclaration` it keeps adding an encoding tag to my declaration.

### My question

Is what I want even possible? And if so could someone explain it to me?

### What I have tried

First I tried to set `OmitXmlDeclaration` to true. But that removes my declaration entirely and then I can't use the XDecleration class at all..

Secondly, when I set my XDecleration to this:

```
new XDeclaration("1.0", string.Empty, "yes")
```

I get this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

and when I set my XDecleration to this:

```
new XDeclaration("1.0", string.Empty, string.Empty)
```

I get this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

So I know that it does respond to what I enter, but the encoding part does not. 
EDIT: I also tried to set the parameters to `null` instead of `string.Empty`. This doesn't work either.

### My Code

```
   public FileResult Download() 
      {
            var doc = new XDocument(
                        new XDeclaration("1.0", string.Empty, string.Empty),
                        new XElement("foo", 
                            new XAttribute("hello", "world")
                        )
                    );

            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var settings = new XmlWriterSettings()
                {
                    OmitXmlDeclaration = false,
                    Indent = true,
                };

                using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings))
                {
                    doc.Save(writer);                    
                }

                stream.Position = 0;

                return File(stream.ToArray(), "text/xml", "HelloWorld.xml");
            }      
      }
```

### EDIT

De solution was given to me by @HimBromBeere. He gave an answer with the following link included.

[cookcomputing.com/blog/archives/000577.html](http://cookcomputing.com/blog/archives/000577.html). Here you overide your encoding parameter. This worked for me.

Comment: As far as I know you need the encoding for a valid XML. However yoiuu may also look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24396776/remove-encoding-from-xmlwriter?rq=1

Comment: @HimBromBeere Ah, looks like I didn't search hard enough. Your answer solved my problem. If you want, change your commentto an answer and I'll accept it as the right answer!

Answer (score 0):

By default XML save method will override the encoding method supplied by us via XDeclaration while saving the Xdocument. The easiest way is to create a memorystream and patch the encoding method. Refer The following code fragment

```
public static void PatchEncoding(string xmlPath,  XDocument xmlDoc, string encoding = "windows-1251")
{
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        using (XmlTextWriter xmlwriter = new XmlTextWriter(stream, Encoding.GetEncoding(encoding)))
        {
            xmlDoc.Save(xmlPath);
        }
}
```